# como puedo intercambiar la posición de palabra en Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

Hola muchachos soy nuevo en el lenguaje de programación **Delphi10** y no se como empezar a realizar este ejercicio, les agradezco quien me puede explicar la elaboración del ejercicio.
¿Cómo puedo cambiar de posición de 4 palabras? : **hola como estas señor** cambia a **cómo hola señor estas**

el código a continuación solo me muestra la última palabra. muchas gracias.

```
procedure TForm2.bcambiarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  frase,palabra, a, letra: string;
  i: integer;
begin
   palabra:= EMPTYSTR;
   frase := (edit1.TEXT);

  for i := 1 to Length(frase) do
  begin
    letra := frase[i];
    if letra <> ' ' then
    begin
      palabra := palabra + letra;
  End
  else
  begin
    palabra:= palabra + letra;
  End;
End;
edit2.TEXT := palabra;
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. 1. Solo la última etiqueta tiene relación con la pregunta, elimina las que no corresponden. 2. Quita la parte de la explicación del ejercicio, ya que las preguntas amplias terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). La finalidad de este sitio es responder a preguntas _específicas_. 3. Dale formato al código colocando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una línea después del mismo.

Comment: Hola. Estaría bien que añadas comentarios al código para indicare qué intentas hacer (//); Hay muchas formas de resolverlo y debes explicar cual has escogido tú. También que nos comentes qué es lo que no te funciona o qué te está fallando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las sugerencias.

Comment: El código anterior: ejemplo si digito la frase " hola como esta" el resultado es = alho omco ates.                                                                                                                     Y en realidad *lo que quiero*   hacer es ejemplo: lo que digito "hola como esta"  resultado = *esta como hola*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con tu comentario queda más claro lo que deseas hacer. El código está bien en parte.
Haciendo unas simples modificaciones puedes conseguir lo que necesitas.

```
var
  frase,palabra, a, letra: string;
  i: integer;
begin
   palabra:= EMPTYSTR;
   frase := (edit1.TEXT);

  for i := 1 to Length(frase) do
  begin
    letra := frase[i];
    if letra <> ' ' then
    begin
        palabra := palabra + letra;
    End
    else
    begin
      // Error --------- palabra:= palabra + letra;
      // (1) Montar la salida final añadiendo las palabras al principio (para que quede invertida)
      edit2.Text := palabra + ' ' + edit2.Text;
      palabra:= EMPTYSTR;
    End;
  End;
  // Error ----------- edit2.TEXT := palabra;
  // (2) Añadir la última palabra
  edit2.Text := palabra + ' ' + edit2.Text;
end;
```

En el **punto (1)** ya tienes la palabra, basta con que las vayas añadiendo a la salida en orden inverso. Y "limpiar" la variable `palabra` para la siguiente pasada del bucle `for`.

En el **punto (2)** sólo debes añadir la última palabra almacenada en la variable, pues en la última pasada por el bucle no la añade.

Con esto tu código funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado y es correcta, marcala (o vótala) para que otros usuarios lo sepan.